# Remove large textblock over multiple lines in python

Tags: python

I have a big pretty big textfile where I need to remove a certain textblock. The text i want to remove starts on row 452 and ends on row 470 and it looks like this:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <None  />
    <None Include="" />
    <None Include="" />
    <None Include="">
      <LogicalName>Info.plist</LogicalName>
    </None>
    <None Include="" />
    <None Include="" />
    <None Include=" ">
      <LogicalName>Info.plist</LogicalName>
    </None>
    <None Include="" />
    <None Include="">
      <LogicalName>Info.plist</LogicalName>
    </None>
    <None Include="Entitlements.plist" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

How could i via my python script remove this? What i've tried to do is the following without success:

```
    with open(os.path.join('folder', 'text.txt'),'r') as file:
    content= file.readlines()
    numb = 451
    toadd=content[451:471]
    for i in range(len(toadd)):
        toadd[i] = toadd[i].replace(toadd[numb], '')
        numb = numb +1

    contout = content - toadd

with open(os.path.join('folder', 'text.txt'),'w') as out:
    out.writelines(contout)
```

Here i try to replace each line inside row 452 and 470 but it does not change anything in the file.

How can i remove a large textblock (approx 20 lines after eachother) in a middle of a textfile?

Comment: Why are you reading this in and manipulating it as raw text? The text is obviously XML, so why not use an XML reader/writer to manipulate it and remove the unwanted elements?

Comment: Maybe thats the best approach. There are many XML elements in my file though and many share the same "name", so for instance there are many different `<ItemGroups>`

Comment: So how did you identify this specific `<ItemGroups>` element that you want to remove? What makes it different than the others that you want to remove it?

Comment: I can only identifiy it now with the current row (i guess) which starts at 452 and ends at 470. Is there any other way i could identify it?

Comment: I"m confused.  You initially say you want to remove a block, but your code appears to insert text....the same text as you removed.

Comment: I'm asking in this case, how did you (manually) pick 452 to 470? Is it because it says for example `"Entitlements.plist"`? Do the others not say that? I'm asking because if there is any element/attribute that is unique you can programmatically find that element rather than using hard-coded line numbers

Comment: @CoryKramer I just saw that Info.plist is unique and only used inside that ItemGroup

Comment: @user1269942 Yea the `contout = content - toadd`might be confusing but im not sure how to "bind it all together" if u know what i mean. But i want to remove the text between row 452 and 470. A XML approach might work too as Cory said. Its a matter of finding it though since many share the same name (ItemGroup)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to remove your block of text. You may need to adjust the numbers in case line number doesn't match the index.

```
with open(os.path.join('folder', 'text.txt'),'r') as file:
    content = file.readlines()

    new_content = content[0:452] + content[471:]

with open(os.path.join('folder', 'new_text.txt'),'w+') as out:
    out.writelines(new_content)
```

Comment: I would consider this answer a bit of a hack though...keep the xml parser idea in the back of your mind when proceeding as it may generalize better...when you have more time and the fires are out.

Comment: Agree with the above comment. Also, you don't know how big this file is. Assuming that each line isn't insanely long, you might consider reading the first 452 lines (modern computers have enough RAM, so fine), writing it out, then looping over the next 20 lines, and then looping line by line and writing out to the file. (Or writing the lines to a buffer and when the buffer exceeds a certain size, write the contents of the buffer to the file). Of course, if OP knows that the file is always going to be fairly small, then fine, this solution will work.